# ping to 8.8.8.8 took long time or even want to show result

Tags: networking, debian, virtual-machine, iptables, ping

Im using ip tables to simulate between host and and client. I can ping between host and client or client between client but the client cannot ping to the 8.8.8.8 or even using internet, but the host can ping and using the internet.
[image]

the topology should look like that but im changing the ip address. For host im using 172.16.6.210 and for the client 172.16.6.220 and 172.16.6.230

this is the main host
[image]
[image]

the clients
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the NAT gateway between the private subnet 172.16.6.0/24 and your publicly routable IP address? Since you didn't mention a NAT gateway, it sounds like maybe you forgot to set one up.

Comment: @Spiff can you teach me how to do it. Im still new at this

Comment: I'm sure you can find an existing tutorial on this. It doesn't make sense for me to try to write a tutorial in the comments.